# Why does it show this error every frame when I press play?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I'm making a spawning system for my game and I have two lists, enemies and spawnpoints. the weird thing is that when I refer to `enemiedata` to get the time between spawning, it gives me this error

> ArgumentException: GetComponent requires that the requested component 'EnemieData' derives from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an interface.

(enemiedata is a scriptable object)

Here's my code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemieSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    //If your game is not Procedurally Generated just drag and drop your spawn points onto this list.
    public List<Transform> spawnPoints;
    public List<GameObject> enemies;
    public bool spawn;
    public float timeSinceLastSpawn;

    public void Update()
    {
        timeSinceLastSpawn += Time.deltaTime;

        if (spawn == true)
        {
            foreach(GameObject enemie in enemies)
            {
                foreach (Transform spawn in spawnPoints)
                {
                    EnemieData enemiedata = enemie.GetComponent<EnemieData>();

                    if (enemiedata.spawnrate >= timeSinceLastSpawn)
                    {
                        SpawnEnemy(spawn, enemie);
                    }
                }

                timeSinceLastSpawn = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    //Method to spawn your enemy at a given point.
    public void SpawnEnemy(Transform spawnPoint, GameObject enemies)
    {
        Instantiate(enemies, spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation);
    }
}
```

Comment: And where is the `EnemieData` script?

Comment: Well, the error message explains the problem. `ScriptableObject` inherits from `Object`. It does not meet the requirements to be a `Component`.

Answer (score 2):

You’ve essentially answered your own question as to why it’s happening. But, to rectify the issue, you’ll have to have a component you can attach to your enemy game object, that includes the EnemieData.

One possible solution might look like:

```cs
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public EnemieData enemyData;
}
```

Then in your enemy spawner, you would modify your existing code to:

```cs
if (enemie.TryGetComponent<Enemy>(out var e))
{
    if (e.enemyData.spawnrate >= timeSinceLastSpawn)
        SpawnEnemy(spawn, enemie);
}
```

Comment: You should also move this before the inner `foreach` loop to avoid unnecessary redundant workload

Comment: now it spawns the enemies without a cooldown. It looks like a long conga line and puts lots of strain on my laptop.

Comment: @bobmaximus what does your code look like now? I was on mobile, so answered with just the bare requirements to resolve your error. On second look at your code, you have two loops, one for enemies and one for spawn points. Is that what you intend?

Comment: What I wanted to is to make it run through every enemy on the list and spawn one of said enemy on every spawnpoint if there has been enough time since the last spawn.